# In XSLT, how to set a price range variable and use it elsewhere in the stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Would like to transform a price into a an expressed price *range* , so that I can say, for example, "Under $20" instead of $ 17.95. Using xml:choose is working for me, but when I try to put the result into a class attribute, I get an error:

*Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown error has occurred ()*

I've been reading up on xsl:variable but cannot seem to find the proper way to set the variable in this case.

The XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <productSearchResponse>
        <status>SUCCESS</status>
        <products found="20">
            <product>
                <itemNumber>50575</itemNumber>
                <itemName>Example 1</itemName>
                <price>$ 17.95</price>
            </product>

            ...

            <product>
                <itemNumber>81588</itemNumber>
                <itemName>Example 2</itemName>
                <price>$ 25.95</price>
            </product>
        </products>
    </productSearchResponse>
```

The stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>          
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/essentials/webservice">
                <xsl:for-each select="document(@filename)/productSearchResponse/products/product">                  
                    <xsl:variable name="producingCountry" select="producingCountry"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="price" select="price"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="priceNoSymbol" select="translate($price,'&#36;', '')"/> 

                    <!-- Assign pricing bands -->                       
                        <xsl:choose>                            
                            <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &lt; '20'">  
                                <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'under20'" />
                            </xsl:when>                             
                            <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &gt; '39.99'">   
                                <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'20to40'" />
                            </xsl:when>                             
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'over40'" /> 
                            </xsl:otherwise>                                
                        </xsl:choose>

                    <!-- Make the product div -->
                        <div class="product {$producingCountry} {$price} {$priceNoSymbol}     ">    
                        <!--           How do I insert priceBand into the class attribute? ^ -->    
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="itemName"/><br/>                           
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="producingCountry"/><br/>                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/><br/><br/>                                                 
                        </div>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>         
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <body>

            <div class="product France $ 17.95 17.95 ">
                Example 1
                <br>
                France
                <br>
                $ 17.95
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="product Portugal $ 25.95 25.95 ">
                Example 2
                <br>
                Portugal
                <br>
                $ 25.95
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Desired html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <body>

            <div class="product France $ 17.95 17.95 under20 ">
                Example 1
                <br>
                France
                <br>
                $ 17.95
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="product Portugal $ 25.95 25.95 20to40">
                Example 2
                <br>
                Portugal
                <br>
                $ 25.95
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is a lousy error message. I think you should tell us what XSLT processor you are using, so that other readers can avoid it. But the cause of the error is that the variables you declare inside the xsl:when clauses are inaccessible outside the xsl:choose.

Comment: @MichaelKay - thanks for the comment and the processor is Firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't studied the entire question in detail, but you should replace

```
<xsl:choose>                            
  <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &lt; '20'">  
    <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'under20'" />
  </xsl:when>                             
  <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &gt; '39.99'">   
    <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'20to40'" />
  </xsl:when>                             
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'over40'" /> 
  </xsl:otherwise>                                
</xsl:choose>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="priceband">
  <xsl:choose>                            
    <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &lt; 20">under20</xsl:when>                             
    <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &lt; 40">20to40</xsl:when>                             
    <xsl:otherwise>over40</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

and

```
<xsl:variable name="priceNoSymbol" select="translate($price,'&#36;', '')"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="priceNoSymbol" select="number(translate($price,'&#36;', ''))"/>
```

When you define a variable inside an `xsl:when` element like that, it goes out of scope almost immediately and isn't available outside the `xsl:choose`.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the explanation. I was able to implement right away (after closing the xsl:choose tag!) and now have a better understanding of this scope issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! I fixed it now though. Incidentally, I forgot to mention I also fixed a logic error- your existing logic would have put anything with $40.00 or greater in the '20to40' class, and anything $20.00 to $39.99 in the 'over40' one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/number) on `$priceNoSymbol` and compare to `20.00` instead of `'20.00'`. You're likely doing string comparison here, which doesn't seem to be what you want. You likely also need to define your `$priceBand` outside of the `xsl:when`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>                     <xsl:choose>                            
>                         <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &lt; '20'">  
>                             <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'under20'" />
>                         </xsl:when>                             
>                         <xsl:when test="$priceNoSymbol &gt; '39.99'">   
>                             <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'20to40'" />
>                         </xsl:when>                             
>                         <xsl:otherwise>
>                             <xsl:variable name="priceBand" select="'over40'" /> 
>                         </xsl:otherwise>                                
>                     </xsl:choose>
> ```

The reason is that the three variables named `priceBand` thus defined, go out ouf scope immediately, and when later you reference such a variable, the resut is "variable undefined" error.

**Use**:

```
               <xsl:variable name="priceBand">                       
                   <xsl:choose>                            
                        <xsl:when test=
                       "$priceNoSymbol &lt; 20">under20</xsl:when>                             
                        <xsl:when test=
                        "$priceNoSymbol > 39.99">20to40</xsl:when>                             
                        <xsl:otherwise>over40</xsl:otherwise>                                
                    </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wish Firefox was clearer with its error messages, but that helps.